# Does checking "Use Auto Layout" in a storyboard convert all of the autoresizing masks?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, autoresizingmask

Currently working on an iPhone app in Xcode 7.3, with some views using autoresizing masks. Does checking "Use Auto Layout" in a storyboard convert all of those masks without any repercussions? I want to make sure this automatic conversion doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked, on my app, it breaks a lot of things.

But just in case you want to experiment and your project is under source control via git, you can try this change and then go to the menu `Source Control -> Discard changes in your.storyboard` to revert the change